# How to get aws cloudwatch metrics statistics using Boto3 AWS Lambda in Python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to getting a Metric DataPoints or Statics from an AWS/Lambda function, Here is the code i running:

```
import boto3
from datetime import timedelta

response = client.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/Lambda',
    MetricName='Invocations',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'lambda',
            'Value': 'my_lambda_name'
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime(2022, 10, 6),
    EndTime=datetime(2022, 10, 8),
    Period=300,
    Statistics=[
        'Sum'
    ],
    #Unit='Count/Second'
    #Unit='Count'
)
response
```

Currently I getting an Empty response as follows:

```
{'Label': 'Invocations',
 'Datapoints': [],
 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'd18c70ee-dedd-410f-afc1-4c32f726175c',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'd18c70ee-dedd-410f-afc1-4c32f726175c',
   'content-type': 'text/xml',
   'content-length': '334',
   'date': 'Fri, 07 Oct 2022 21:29:50 GMT'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

However, I really sure that the lambda is currently Invoking as the following graph shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just find a solution assigning the Dimensions Name and Value as follows:

```
import boto3
from datetime import timedelta

response = client.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/Lambda',
    MetricName='Invocations',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'FunctionName',
            'Value': 'my_function_name'
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime(2022, 10, 6),
    EndTime=datetime(2022, 10, 8),
    Period=300,
    Statistics=[
        'Sum'
    ],
)
response
```